# Dart UDP socket won't timeout

Tags: dart, sockets, udp

I want to create a UDP socket that broadcasts some data, then listens for responses from an arbitrary number of devices for 5 seconds (some code to support multiple responses has been removed for simplicity).  The code below broadcasts as expected and receives responses as expected, but it never times out and appears to be listening forever.
I would think that the `timeout` function would simply set the timeout of the socket, but instead it seems to do nothing except return an instance of `Stream<RawSocketEvent>` which seems unhelpful unless I'm missing something.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future <void> sendData() async {
  List<int> buffer = utf8.encode('foobar');
  RawDatagramSocket s = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress('192.168.1.123'), 0);  // My PC's IP
  s.broadcastEnabled = true;

  // A call to `timeout` returns an instance of `Stream<RawSocketEvent>`, so I
  // don't expect this to do anything the way I have it implemented, but a
  // timeout of 5 seconds on the listen is what I'm trying to accomplish.
  s.timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
  var subscription = s.listen((RawSocketEvent e) async {
    Datagram? dg = s.receive();
    if (dg != null) {
      print('Received:');
      print(utf8.decode(dg.data));
    }
  });

  s.send(buffer, InternetAddress('255.255.255.255'), 1234);
  await subscription.asFuture<void>(); // Never gets past here
  s.close();
}


Future<void> main() async {
  await sendData();
  exit(0);
}
```

I've tried several variations on this code, but I always get one of two results; `listen` never times out, or `main` returns before any data is received on the socket (but `send` was successful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timeout` function doesn't set the timeout as one would expect, but instead creates a separate stream which you have to listen to.  Not intuitive, but the code below does works well on both UDP and TCP sockets.  Note that the `timeout` field in a TCP socket's `connect` function is only a timeout for the initial connection, not a timeout for how long the connection should be maintained.  That is why code similar to this will also be needed when setting a TCP socket's "how long to listen after connection" timeout:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future <void> sendData() async {
  List<int> buffer = utf8.encode('foobar');
  RawDatagramSocket s = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress('192.168.1.123'), 0);  // My PC's IP
  Stream<RawSocketEvent> streamController = s.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5), onTimeout: (sink) => sink.close());
  s.broadcastEnabled = true;

  StreamSubscription streamSubscription = streamController.listen((RawSocketEvent rawSocketEvent) async {
    Datagram? dg = s.receive();
    if (dg != null) {
      print('Received:');
      print(utf8.decode(dg.data));
    }
  });

  s.send(buffer, InternetAddress('255.255.255.255'), 1234);
  
  // Wait for the socket to be done listening for a response
  await streamSubscription.asFuture<void>();
}


main() async {
  await sendData();
  exit(0);
}
```